# Recording streaming video from my computer

Tags: streaming

How would you go about recording a WebEx session that's being played in the Network Recording Player (not browser)? I cannot save the WebEx session so I thought of having a screen capture software that will record as the WebEx session is playing and then I need to capture the audio part of the WebEx session too. So how would I go about setting it up such that I start the streaming video, then 2-3 hours later I have all that stuff in an AVI file or something of that sort?

Comment: I thought WebEx offered a download copy once the conference was finished?

Answer (score 1):

Standard screen-recording software such as [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/) will work for this.

Answer (score 0):

[Quicktime Player X](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/) will take high-quality screen recording. The best thing is that it's free!! I'm on a Mac, and it will take screen recordings. If you are on a PC, I don't know if this feature works. Let me know if it doesn't work on a PC.

Answer (score -1):

I used the Quicktime screen recorder to record some full-screen video art, and I noticed that it is very compressed, and I didn't see any options to change settings. The rich color of the art was squished into a smaller color space, and there were visible compression artifacts. But I'm sure it is fine for recording tutorials and such.